# How do I clear deprecation errors for looping through element queries?

Tags: templating, error-message

I am getting this depreciation messages.

> Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them.

In the example below, **the depreciation message refers to the 2nd `loop` `for flag in country`**.  The message appears anytime I have a loop within a loop.

**How do I template this to avoid the deprecation message?**

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('posts').all() %}

{% for first in entries[0:1] %}

{% set country = first.countryName %}

{% for flag in country %} 
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ flag.countryCode }}"></span>
{% endfor %}

<span>{{ first.title }}</span>

 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using the `all()` function as well? Your field doesn't contain an array, it contains the same type of object like `craft.entries` provides.

```
{% for flag in country.all() %}
```

It doesn't appear because you have a loop in a loop it appears because you treat and object as an array